# IOS 13 SplitViewController Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ios13

On iOS 13 I currently have problems with my UISplitViewController on IPAD app.

MY masterViewcontroller is not loaded while launching in ios 13 wherein ios 12 it works fine . My code is in objective c and we are using xibs since it is old code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with iOS 13 Split view controller using IB. If you have navigation controller embedded to Master/Detail view controller it just loads the navigation controller.

To fix that issue create a custom class from UISplitViewController and assign that to your splitviewcontroller in storyboard and programatically add Navigation controller and masterViewcontroller to that UISplitViewController. That should load your view properly.
This code goes in the viewdidload or willappear of the UISplitviewcontroller class.
Sample code.

```
 MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
 UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];
 UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableViewNavigationController,navC, nil];
```

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Still could not able to fix the issue